# Number_format PDO results

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Hey guys so I'm just wondering how it is possible to format numbers when display data from a MySQL table using PDO?

At the moment I am printing my data using the following code:

```
<?php while($row = $results->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
      {
      echo '<div>

           '.$row["Price"].'

           </div>
      ';
      } ?>
```

I have tried implementing number_format into my PHP however I keep getting a parse error.

Any idea how I can implement it properly so that my numbers contain commas?

Thanks

Comment: What code, what syntax error?

Comment: *"I have tried implementing number_format into my PHP however I keep getting a parse error."* - Show us how you've tried to use it, including the full error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
while($row = $results->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{
echo '<div>

    '.number_format($row['price'], 2, ',', '.').'

      </div>
';
  }
```

Should do the trick. 
Maybe you tried without the last parameter of number format, the function takes one, two or four parameters.

Comment: You might want to use a complete statement there so that both the syntax highlighter and a casual reader don't mistake your code for syntax errors.

Comment: Hi! Just tried this and the formatting is working however here is the output: £5.789,00

As you can see it's adding two 0's which I don't really need and adding the comma to the wrong place. I'm sure this is just becuase the number_function needs configuring a little. Thanks I'll do some experimenting

Comment: the 2 in the number format is the number of decimals, set it to 0 to remove them. switch the comma and the dot if you want british notation, from your wuestion I thought you needed a comma as a decimal point, like we do here in the Netherlands ;)